# PHP - Form not submiteed on additional file upload button

Tags: php, html, isset

I have a following code with 5 file-upload buttons.
The 4 of them works properly, but when I insert the 5th upload button, my form is not submitted.
i.e. It redirects to the action page but `isset()` is not called.

**HTML**

```
    <form action="g.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


            <div class="col-lg-4 ">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputName">Upload Photograph: </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                            <input type="file" name="stud_photo" id="stud_photo" required>
                                </span>
                            </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

 <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputName">Upload Course Admissoin Receipt: </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                            <input type="file" name="course_admission_receipt" id="course_admission_receipt" required>
                                </span>
                            </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 ">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputName">Upload Health Certificate: </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                            <input type="file" name="health_certificate" id="health_certificate" required>
                                </span>
                            </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-push-1">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputName">Upload Character Certificate: </label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                                            <input type="file" name="character_certificate" id="character_certificate" required />

                                </span>
                            </span>
                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-push-1">
        <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="InputName">Upload Residence Certificate: </label>
            <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">

                        <input type="file" name="resident_certificate" id="resident_certificate" />
                                </span>
                            </span>

                        </div>
                </div>
        <div>    

</div> <!-- row-->

    <div class="center">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" name="register" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">                            
        </div>


</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
echo "Im goin in <br>";

if(isset($_POST['register'])){
    echo "im here";
}

else{
    echo "I am not there";
}

?>
```

Only when I insert the last **Upload Residence certificate** button, It goes into else block.

Comment: I copied your code, its entering `if()`

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju Did you try uploading all 5 buttons?

Comment: Except the code you have added for php, is there anything else in `g.php`??

Comment: No.. There is nothing in that file. I also tried copying both the files in different directory also. Does `Bootstrap CSS/JS ` has anything to do with it?

Comment: No... But just remove and try... But i dont think that will make any difference.

Comment: I tried that also. Now my files have same code as that of what I mentioned above. I also tried restarting WAMP Server.

Comment: have `print_r($_POST)` and see what values are getting posted.

Comment: When I try with only 4 uploads, I get: `Array ( [register] => Submit Form ) `
Whereas with 5 I get `Array( )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was neither in HTML code nor in PHP. 
I checked my php.ini file and there I found this line

```
post_max_size = 3M
```

I changed it to

```
post_max_size = 30M
```

This means at max 30 Mb of data can be posed using $_POST method. 
Since I was uploading images `(800-1000kb)` each, It was exceeding the max size.
Changing the value worked.

Answer (score 2):

Just above the submit button, You have an error in html,

```
<div>    // this div should be a closing div

</div> <!-- row-->
```

Something like this,

```
</div>    

</div> <!-- row-->
```

Comment: thanks for bringing that into notice. But it didn't affect .

Comment: @VishalKinjavdekar I have one more doubt, what is the name of your 5th upload button??

Comment: `resident_certificate` I tried it on another machine and there its working fine. I think my problem is with Apache or Wamp Server itself.